# Как сделать функцию на подобие .toString()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Мне надо сделать функцию, которая выполняется с строкой.
Тип
`"кек".toLatin()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
String.prototype.toLatin = function(){
  var res = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var ch = this.charAt(i);
    switch (ch) {
      case 'а': ch = 'a'; break;
      case 'б': ch = 'b'; break;
      // .............
      case 'е': ch = 'e'; break;
      // .............
      case 'к': ch = 'k'; break;
      // .............
    }
    res += ch;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log('кек'.toLatin());
```

Answer (score 2):

Через [прототип](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype) -

```js
String.prototype.toLatin = function(){
    return `kek`;
}

console.log('кек'.toLatin());
```